# Kentico CMS Mobile Site shows different content

Tags: kentico

our corporate website is based on the Kentico (ver 8) CMS platform, and for some reason, it shows different (outdated) content if the website is opened on a mobile phone browser (tested with iPhone and Android as well). It is a responsive site and we don't have different/separate sites for mobile/PC, it is a common site, so any changes made to the site should automatically get updated on the PC as well as on the mobile.

To be more specific, this is what's happening - we had 1100 employees about 3 years and, and we are currently at 1600 employees. For some reason, our mobile view has gone back 3 years and it shows 1100 employees instead of 1600. Weird issue. I tried disabling "Device profiles" in Settings > Content > Content management > Mobile development > Enable device profiles - still no luck! Please help!

PS: I'm not very familiar with the Kentico platform, so please do not assume anything and please provide detailed responses.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the site is responsive? If you open it on your desktop and shrink the browser down to mobile size, does it show the mobile view?

If it has device profiles enabled, it might be using different templates for mobile and desktop views.

Make sure you clear the site cache, System > Clear cache.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt response. Yes, the site is responsive. If I open it on my computer it shows the latest version. However, if I resize/shrink the browser on the same computer/same browser window, it immediately shows an outdated version. I tried clearing the cache several times, still no luck! Also, as I mentioned in my original post above, Device Profiles have been disabled ("Enable Device Profiles" checbox is unchecked).

Comment: If shrinking your browser down without doing a page refresh causes the content to change and display the wrong information, then it sounds like the design is hiding some information and displaying other information in the different views. I would assume that would be 2 different web parts, and one was updated but not the other.  Do you know if it was built using portal engine?

Comment: You are right! There are two different webparts - one for the mobile view and another one for the computer. How silly !!... I guess it will have to be uploaded in both locations now. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Sometimes 2 webparts are needed although they should be using the same datasource so the query is only run once and not several times per page load.  You might look at modifying this so both webparts use a single datasource so it doesn't happen again.